# Glimpse.MiniProfiler plugin not showing duration

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler, glimpse

When I use MiniProfiler plugin for Glimpse, the duration column is not showing anything.
What could be missing? Anyone experienced the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer behind this plugin.

The problem is that the plugin is collecting data before the request ends. The thing is that it's not obvious how to collect data in that situation and I'm working on that.

I'll update this answer when I fix the problem.

Ths ticket can be found here: https://github.com/mcliment/miniprofiler-glimpse-plugin/issues/2

Comment: Please post back when you have a solution for this. Great plugin nonetheless!

Comment: Hi Marc, any progress on this? The duration not showing really killed this awesome plugin, please make it work again, thanks

Comment: I'm working on it, new versions of Miniprofiler don't offer all the necessary data when Glimpse needs it.